# What is the thick, dashed, magenta line on a sectional chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

In the attached area of the sectional chart we see restricted areas R-2101 and R-2102. Also covering that general area is a circular, thick, dashed magenta line. There's a notice there that I assume corresponds to it, but I wasn't familiar with this marking before I saw it. I glanced at the [Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) but didn't see a reference. Anyone know what's happening here?

[image: sectional thick dashed lined]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Atlanta sectional [near KANB, KASN, and KPLR](https://skyvector.com/?ll=33.621404670280945,-85.91033934962762&chart=301&zoom=2) gives a hint:

> FOR REASONS OF NATIONAL SECURITY
> PILOTS ARE REQUESTED TO AVOID FLIGHT
> AT AND BELOW 5000’ AGL IN THIS AREA

It is called a [National Security Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Area), which FAA’s training [ALC-42: Airspace, Special Use Airspace and TFRs](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/course_content.aspx?cID=42&sID=243) describes as follows.

> **National Security Areas**
>
> National Security Areas consist of airspace of defined vertical and lateral dimensions established at locations where there is a requirement for increased security and safety of ground facilities. Pilots are requested to voluntarily avoid flying through the depicted NSA. When it is necessary to provide a greater level of security and safety, flight in NSAs may be temporarily prohibited by regulation under the provisions of [14 CFR Section 99.7](http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=224f4caa299238689ebdbf7c741e5725&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.14.1.9.4&idno=14). Regulatory prohibitions will be issued by System Operations, System Operations Airspace and AIM Office, Airspace and Rules, and disseminated via NOTAM. Inquiries about NSAs Inquiries should be directed to Airspace and Rules.
>
> Example — National Security Area near Pueblo, Co. and request to avoid flight at and below 3000’ AGL.
>
> [image: National Security Area near Publeo, Colorado]

Wikipedia gives a [brief description](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/course_content.aspx?cID=42&sID=243).

> In United States aviation, a National Security Area is a designated airspace through which flight is discouraged for reasons of national security.
>
> Flight through NSAs is not prohibited and no special advance clearance or authorization need be obtained to enter them. However, pilots of aircraft are strongly encouraged to either stay clear of NSAs or obtain prior authorization to pass through them in order to reassure the controlling agency that no threat to national security exists.
>
> NSAs are a compromise between normal airspace and restricted or prohibited airspace. NSAs can be temporarily converted into restricted airspace by NOTAMs.
>
> On VFR sectional charts, NSAs are delimited by a heavy dashed magenta border and a special notation.

Answer (score 5):

The thick dashed magenta line indicates a National Security Area.

> National Security Areas indicated with a broken magenta line national security area dashes and Special Flight Rules Areas (SFRAs) indicated with the following symbol: sfras , consist of airspace with defined vertical and lateral dimensions established at locations where there is a requirement for increased security and safety of ground facilities. Pilots should avoid flying through these depicted areas. When necessary, flight may be temporarily prohibited.

The answer is in the [Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/), I just initially overlooked it.

[image: aero chart user's guide]

Answer (score 1):

National Security Area.

[image]
([source](http://flighttraining.aopa.org/pdfs/Intro_to_VFR_Chart_Symbols.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are "National Security Areas" which are marked with a dashed magenta line. Here is the description from the guide:

> National Security Areas indicated with a broken magenta line and
>   Special Flight Rules Areas (SFRAs) indicated with the following
>   symbol: , consist of airspace with defined vertical and lateral
>   dimensions established at locations where there is a requirement for
>   increased security and safety of ground facilities. Pilots should
>   avoid flying through these depicted areas. When necessary, flight may
>   be temporarily prohibited.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I was asking for the sake of utilizing the chart in general, not in a way specific to this area. This might make a better comment.

Comment: @RyanBurnette I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I am familiar with both restricted and prohibited areas. The thick dashed line I'm referring to is neither.

Comment: The "R-_2101_" marking seems to be pointing at the blue hatched area nearby, not the red circle. R-2102 is the larger hatched area above it.

Comment: Hmm, right, I have updated my answer, apparently it is a "National Security Area" which means they have alien bodies there or something.

Comment: Yea I found it in the guide too. I can't find something like this until I've bothered to post it as a question on SE. ;)

Comment: @TylerDurden It basically means "we don't want anyone ramming a plane into anything here or taking photographs too closely," though, of course, nowadays, you could take excellent photographs from 3,000' (or 5,000' as the case may be.) The nuclear research facility close to where I live has one of these, for example.